# Change different classes to each <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a list and am trying to add a different class name to each

. Currently, this my work:

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-color">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var color=['red-dark','orange-dark','orange','yellow','grey','green','green-dark'];
    $('#navbar-color ul li').each(function(i){
        $(this).addClass(colors[i]);
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change `$('#navbar-color" ul li'` to `$('#navbar-color li'`

Comment: still didn't work. here my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Suhindra/5kynvkr9/

Comment: Here you go, Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5kynvkr9/1/)

Comment: @Suhindra , check my answer. you are using var color= and after getting valuse as colors{i]. both variable different with "s".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selection is failing, since your are catching the `<ul>` with the id and trying to find a `<ul>` within it.

As @Tushar said use the following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var color=['red-dark','orange-dark','orange','yellow','grey','green','green-dark'];
    $('#navbar-color li').each(function(i){ // remove ul
        $(this).addClass(color[i]);
    });
});
```

You also have an extra double quote `$('#navbar-color"` that shall be removed

Comment: Thank you. I suck at js, I thought I give it a shot. Thank you and @Tushar for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

Please check correctly your color variable.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rL2pr0r9/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = ['red-dark', 'orange-dark', 'orange', 'yellow', 'grey', 'green', 'green-dark'];
  $('#navbar-color ul li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(color[i]);
  });
});
```

```css
.red-dark {
  color: red;
}
.orange-dark {
  color: orange;
}
.orange {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-color">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code ::
check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/095wn6ms/
HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-color">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var color=['red-dark','orange-dark','orange','yellow','grey','green','green-dark'];
    $('#navbar-color ul li').each(function(i){
        $(this).addClass(color[i]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using wrong variable name in the each loop `clolors` for the array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = ['red-dark', 'orange-dark', 'orange', 'yellow', 'grey', 'green', 'green-dark'];
  $('#navbar-color ul li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(color[i]);
  });
});
```

```css
.red-dark {
  color: red;
}
.orange-dark {
  color: blue;
}
.orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-color">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```